# JQuery dropdown list values to php array?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

How can I pass all the values from one dropdown list to one PHP array?

Let's say that I have one dropdownlist name="country" and id="countries"
Options:
val="Japan" Japan
val="USA" USA
val="UK" UK

How can I parse the values to one PHP array?

The content is generated dynamically from another dropdownlist by chained method.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend serializing all the values using JSON and decoding the JSON on the server.